# How to know user has click on any activity screen from 1 place in Application

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, android-fragments, countdowntimer

I have created a timer, that starts when user opens the application. When user does any activity the timer needs to get reset.

I don't want to go to each activity and reset timer on user actions. I want to handle this globally from one place. Is it possible to get user action in Main Application, and reset timer from there.

So i won't need to do following in each activity.

```
@overide
public void onUserInteraction() {
     super.onUserInteraction();     
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can define a base Activity and then have all your activities extend it.
That way you can add the method to the base activity and it will be available in all of your activities.

Comment: Thanks, can i do this from the Application class?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by doing it from the Application class. Simply extend Activity and add there whatever methods you need. Then have all your "real" activities extend that new class instead of extending the class Activity. If the timer is in the Application class then have your method call it from there.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Utility class and add a static variable inside it.
Then change its value when the intent is triggered.

Utility class

```
public class Utility {
    public static boolean isActivityTriggered = false;
}
```

Change its value when you trigger Intent to MyActivity

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
Utility.isActivityTriggered = true;
```

With this whenever you start MyActivity from MainActivity, the boolean will be set to true.

Answer (score 0):

In your class that extends `Application` add a static method

```
public static void onUserInteraction() {
    //cancel the timer
}
```

Then from any activity call `MyApplication.onUserInteraction();`